# Problem in installing Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

I am getting this issue.

```
 passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Already installed Apache2 and passenger gem

```
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/apache.rb:277:in `_unmemoized_apr_config_needed_for_building_apache_modules?': undefined local variable or method `test_exe_outdir' for PhusionPassenger::PlatformInfo:Module (NameError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb:92:in `apr_config_needed_for_building_apache_modules?'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.6/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:69:in `dependencies'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_installer.rb:166:in `check_dependencies'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.6/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:90:in `install!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_installer.rb:63:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.6/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:236
        from /usr/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:19:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:--

1. Compile the passenger source code. You can download it from [here](http://www.modrails.com/install.html)

   To install Passenger from source code, extract the source tarball:

   ```
   tar xzvf passenger-X.X.X.tar.gz
   ```

   Then run the included installer:

   ```
   ./passenger-X.X.X/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
   ```

   passenger-install will notify about the missing dependencies. Install them
2. You may get an issue that ssl is not installed if you are using ruby 1.9.2. Try this:-

   ```
   cd to : /usr/local/src/ruby-1.9.2-p00/ext/openssl (or whatever)  
   sudo ruby extconf.rb
   make install
   ```
3. run the previous command ie

   ```
    ./passenger-X.X.X/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
   ```

and it will work like a charm. :-)

Comment: Maybe your Ruby got compiled without OpenSSl support and that's causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

This issue had been fixed, see the first comment at here:
http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=653
and 
https://github.com/henare/passenger/compare/issue-653

In fact, just need to edit the ".../apache.rb" file, and replace "test_exe_outdir" with "tmpexedir".

Comment: @user618981 things worked for after compiling the source code. Check answer posted by me.anyways thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a [bug in the Passenger installer](http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=653&sort=id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Stars%20Summary&start=100), but it only seems to be triggered if either `apr-config` or `apu-config` are missing. These are part of the `apr` package, or `apr-devel` on some systems where the development version is optional.

When it starts up and displays diagnostics it should show something like this:

```
Checking for required software...

 * GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
 * Curl development headers with SSL support... found
 * OpenSSL development headers... found
 * Zlib development headers... found
 * Ruby development headers... found
 * OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
 * RubyGems... found
 * Rake... found at /opt/local/rvm/wrappers/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/rake
 * rack... found
 * Apache 2... found at /usr/sbin/httpd
 * Apache 2 development headers... found at /usr/sbin/apxs
 * Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers... found at /usr/bin/apr-1-config
 * Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers... found at /usr/bin/apu-1-config
```

If it crashes before getting to that point, you can coach the installer on which APR and APU to use with command line options.

I can't get 3.0.6 to install under Ruby 1.8.7 either, it's trashed during the C++ compile phase, so I can't replicate this problem. I haven't had trouble before, though.

Comment: Depends on your platform, but install `apr` and `apu` with the development headers.

Comment: check solution posted by me. Thanks for your help.